# Optimize Multiple Joins SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, performance, left-join

I need to join all columns from one table (table A) to single columns in two other tables (B & C). My SQL works but is pretty slow. The problem is coming from joining A and C. I've looked into optimizing but haven't found anything to speed it up. Unfortunately, I can't alter the table design.

```
SELECT tableA.*, 
       tableB.user_email,
       tableC.transaction_number 
FROM tableA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB 
   ON tableA.user_id=tableB.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableC 
   ON tableA.user_id=tableC.user_id 
   AND A.timestamp=C.timestamp 
ORDER BY A.timestamp DESC;
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: And what does the `EXPLAIN` output show? Which indexes are being used?

Comment: As well as the EXPLAIN, questions about query performance ALWAYS require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & [mcve]. What does "looked into optimizing" mean? It doesn't seem to have involved reading about fundamentals of SQL optimization, or reading a lot of SO Qs & As re sql optimization, or reading all the mentions of 'optimization' in the MySQL manual. PS That code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

For your query, you want indexes on `tableB(id, user_email)` and `tableC(user_id, timestamp, transaction_number)` and `tableA(timestamp, user_id)`.

I'm not sure if you can do better than that.

Comment: the index on tableC could include `timestamp` column (before `transaction_number` column) ,,,  there's an equality predicate on that column as well as `user_id`

Comment: tableA:  `INDEX (timestamp)`  -- for `ORDER BY`; adding columns won't help